# What can be the reasons for me being no more able to share to Google+ communities?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

I did share successfully 2 posts to a G+ community beginning of April 2015 and now I tried doing it again (to the same community) last week.

The post shows up in the community when using my account (and on my profile). However, it is not showing up when looking up the community page using another account.

I tried to ask on *Google+ Help*-community what might be wrong, but as it is a community no one will see my post - except me.

What might have happened?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is most likely that it is marked as spam and has landed in a moderation queue the OWNER of a community can handle.

Or can simply ignore it (my case) which leaves you stunned and unknown.

This Google+ post tells you possible reason why have are considered a spammer.

https://plus.google.com/+JohnSkeats/posts/R9y9VtUPxSh